# Translate SQL Query in EF Framework Query

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, join

I am trying to write this SQL Query in EF Framework

```
SELECT id, name, (
    select count(*) > 0 from restaurants_badges as rb
        where rb.badge_id = b.id
        and rb.restaurant_id = ''
      ) as checked
FROM badges as b;
```

As you can see from the picture below, I need a third column with a boolean value that tells me if a specific restaurant has the badge, and of course I need all the the records inside the table badges:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/35aVd.png

The result of this query should enter in a DTO. This is what I am writing in the code:

```
        // Method to check what badges have the specific restaurant
        public List<BadgeDTO> CheckBadgesInRestaurant(string restaurantId)
        {
            return _context.RestaurantBadges
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(rb => rb.RestaurantId.Equals(restaurantId))
                .LeftJoin(_context.Badges, rb => rb.BadgeId,
                b => b.Id,
                (rb, b) => new BadgeDTO
                {
                    Id = b.Id,
                    Name = b.Name,
                    Check = rb.RestaurantId.Count() > 0
                })
                .ToList();
        }
```

I am getting this error when the function gets executed: 'Specified method is not supported'.
Am I using the context in a wrong way? How should I write this SQL query with EF Framework?

---

SOLUTION FOUND!
It was easier than I thought

```
    public List<BadgeDTO> CheckBadgesInRestaurant(string restaurantId)
    {
        return _context.Badges
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Select(b => new BadgeDTO()
            {
                Id = b.Id,
                Name = b.Name,
                Check = _context.RestaurantBadges
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(br => br.BadgeId == b.Id && br.RestaurantId == restaurantId)
                    .Any()
            }).OrderBy(b => b.Id)
            .ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the model classes and also the table structure? Stackoverflow editor now has a feature that allows you to use tables. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)